# Extension method for a type writing the <T>

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

In .NET I could get a `List<PropertyInfo>` using the following

```
obj.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
```

in order to make it nicer I did

```
public static IList<PropertyInfo> GetPropertyInfo<T>(this T obj)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
}
```

but something uglier came up, which is

```
obj.GetPropertyInfo<Wrapper>();
```

but I was wondering how can I avoid the `<T>` the way they avoid it?

Why can't it just be

```
obj.GetPropertyInfo();
```

Comment: Please don't edit your question to show the solution, mark the answer that helped you as accepted, instead.

Comment: @Sklivvz but the problem is i am not sure if its a good solution so i thought of it as a part of the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason why you cannot drop the `T` generic parameter from your extension method, because you are not using that generic parameter anywhere!

So, please write:

```
public static IList<PropertyInfo> GetPropertyInfo(this object obj)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a method with generic type argument? Couldn't your method just be like following?

```
public static IList<PropertyInfo> GetPropertyInfo(this object obj)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is why you made this method generic, if call GetType of object instance.
Just remove generic.

```
public static IList<PropertyInfo> GetPropertyInfo(this T obj)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your method to take parameter of `System.Type` type and remove the `GetType()` invocation:

```
public static IList<PropertyInfo> GetPropertyInfo(this Type obj)
{
    return obj.GetProperties().ToList();
}
```

In this case you could use it as follows:

```
var propertyInfos = typeof(MyType).GetPropertyInfo();
```

Comment: you made it even uglier ;)